# Very confusing table to make a selection tool in Excel

Tags: excel

Here is the scenario. I have a box that comes in 2 sizes, 200 ft and 400 ft. For each size, they have their own weight and measurement constraints, and their respective costs.

> 200 ft:
>   Weight constraint: 21  ton,
>   measurement constraint: 25 m,
>   Cost: $750
>
> 400 ft:
>   Weight constraint: 24 ton,
>   measurement constraint: 40 m,
>   Cost: $1050

I have to come out with a selection tool whereby by inputing the weight and measurement into the excel spreadsheet, the Excel will generate the most appropriate and cost efficient selection of container, and the respective costs. For example, if 20 ton and 40 m was inputed, the Excel will generate the correct combination of containers that I need with the costs.

I am currently able to do only for one size of containers, I am unable to do it if I have to combine both together, which I desperately need to.

Here is an example of what I did:

```
=IF(($E$12/Data!$E$12)>($F$12/Data!$G$12),ROUNDUP($E$12/Data!$E$12,0),ROUNDUP($F$12/Data!$G$12,0)))
```

Answer (score 1):

The Solver Add-In can be used to perform this calculation. The images below show how this can be accomplished.

**The spreadsheet used to generate the results:**
[image]

**The solver setup:**
[image]

**The results for the input specified above**
[image]

Comment: Could you explain about the solver setup portion under the constraints where $B$10 =  integer. Thanks!

Comment: Sure. The integer constraint ensures that you don't end up with a solution that recommends, for example, 1.5 200 ft containers, or 3.25 400 ft containers. Presumably, you can only have an integral number of each container (0, 1, 2, ...). If this assumption is invalid, you can remove this constraint.

Comment: I think I got it. But is there a way to just input in the tons and meters and have the calculations appear without clicking the solver everytime there is a change in tons or meters?

Comment: You could create a macro to automatically run the solver, insert a button that will run the macro, or tie the macro to a hotkey. Note that there may be a greedy algorithm that will correctly optimize the containers. This is just one of many methods that can be employed to solve your problem.

Comment: Is there any way to combine the IF formula with the solver tool? For example, I am using the formula to show that IF cell A1 is a number, A2 will be shown as 0. But if it is false, A2 will use the solver tool instead.       =IF(NOT)(ISNUMBER(A1)),0, SOLVER TOOL)